# How to display the image in JLabel?

Tags: image

it seems that i can't show the image in my interface the buttons are appearing but the images are not displaying. Is there any lacking code that i need to put? Thanks in advance!
Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
JFrame frame = new JFrame("#RoadToPhysicalFitness");
frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));

JPanel paneB = new JPanel();
JPanel paneI = new JPanel();
JPanel paneA = new JPanel();

paneB.setLayout(new BoxLayout(paneB,BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
paneI.setLayout(new BoxLayout(paneI,BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
paneA.setLayout(new BoxLayout(paneA,BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

JLabel IconB = new JLabel();
JLabel IconI = new JLabel();
JLabel IconA = new JLabel();

ImageIcon IcoB = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("‪C:\\Users\\banjawanja\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\JavaApplication1\\‪C:\\Users\\banjawanja\\Desktop\\Beginner.jpg").getImage().getScaledInstance(100,100, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
ImageIcon IcoI = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("‪C:\\Users\\banjawanja\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\JavaApplication1\\‪C:\\Users\\banjawanja\\Desktop\\Intermediate.jpg").getImage().getScaledInstance(100,100,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
ImageIcon IcoA = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("‪C:\\Users\\banjawanja\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\JavaApplication1\\‪C:\\Users\\banjawanja\\Desktop\\Advanced.jpg").getImage().getScaledInstance(100,100, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));

    System.out.println(new File("‪C:\\Users\\banjawanja\\Desktop\\Beginner.jpg").getAbsolutePath());

IconB.setIcon(IcoB);
IconI.setIcon(IcoI);
IconA.setIcon(IcoA);

JButton btnB = new JButton("Beginner");
JButton btnI = new JButton("Intermediate");
JButton btnA = new JButton("Advanced");

paneB.add(IconB);
paneB.add(btnB);

paneI.add(IconI);
paneI.add(btnI);

paneA.add(IconA);
paneA.add(btnA);

frame.add(paneB);
frame.add(paneI);
frame.add(paneA);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if it's your only problem but in the description of the url you have two urls together ...

Like:

`newImageIcon("‪C:\\Users\\banjawanja\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\JavaApplication1\\`HERE`‪C:\\Users\\banjawanja\\Desktop\\Beginner.jpg").getImage()`

Are you sure that is the correct URL?

A Greeting

Comment: Hello sir sorry for late response. I remove the "C:" and changed it to `ImageIcon IcoI = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("‪C:\\Users\\banjawanja\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\JavaApplication5\\int.jfif").getImage().getScaledInstance(100,100,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));`But it still doesnt show up. i also tried the format :`ImageIcon IcoB = new ImageIcon("‪C:\\Users\\banjawanja\\Desktop\\beg.jfif");
IcoB = new ImageIcon(IcoB.getImage().getScaledInstance(100,100, BufferedImage.SCALE_SMOOTH));` What could be the error?